# Microsoft Outlook - Advanced Find - Find Person from Global Directory simply by Typing

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to find some emails by specific person that is in my company's global directory list. In the Advanced Find Dialog, I can see **From...** option, and when I click on it, it allows me to search through Global Directory List and insert the name of the person (e.g. John Doe). However, if I simply type the name of the person, it does not identify the person.

It is kind of tedious to always search for the name of the person, when I exactly know the name. Is it possible to enable Global directory validated name by simply typing in the **From: Textbox**?

Hope I am making sense. Thank you. Any other suggestions or recommendation are much appreciated. Thank you.

[image: type person name in outlook advanced find]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to enable Global directory validated name by simply typing in the From: Textbox?

Seems like there's no option available to enable the auto validation when you typing in the From field in the Advanced Find dialogue box. You can send a feature request via the MS feedback portal for Outlook here:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/89a8afa3-2e1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

However, if the name you type is unique, based on my test, it's not necessary to validate the name. Just type the name and go ahead clicking **Find Now**, the results can still show up.

Comment: Thanks Yuki. In my case, it did not search.

Comment: That's weird though. How about using the Instant Search box at the top of the Outlook window, you can type: "From: John Doe", then hit Enter to perform the search.

Comment: Yes. i can search through Instant Searchbox on the top of Outlook. However, that raises another question. I have to select the folder in order to search. But let's say, I am searching for email that I sent to `john doe`. I have to select `Sent` folder and then search for `From:myname`. It is annoying.

Comment: If you use the Advanced Find feature, you also need to Select Items folder, isn't it?